# Integrate Service Reference into C# Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest

Hi I'm trying to integrate a web service into a class in C#, but I want to make the service reference stand alone in that class.

I want someone to be able to use this class in their projects without them having to add a service reference via Visual Studio.

It's hard to describe, and I'm not really sure to look to find it so i apologise if this is a really simple bit of knowledge.

How would I go about doing this? The web service I want to integrate uses REST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward.  Create your class library project, add the service reference to this project.  Build the API 'on top' of the service that you want to expose to consumers of this library.  You can now ship this class library and clients/consumers of it will simply add it as a local reference, no need to add a service reference as the service reference exists 'inside' of the shipped assembly. You may need to consider allowing clients to configure your library with the endpoint URL, or you may be happy to hard code the endpoint, your call.

Answer (score 1):

The service reference is just a wrapper around the functionality of [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).  If you want to just generate the service proxy and use it "as source", you just follow the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx

EDIT: Missed, until just now, that this is a REST service.  Not sure whether svcutil works with REST.